# Redirect (>) command does not print some tail of output to file

Tags: python, file, terminal, command

I tried to print output result of my python program to log file using by this command:

```
./project.py > result.log
```

And when i opened `result.log` i found one problem. It missed some tail of output i think it's about 5 - 15 of the last lines

How to solve this problem?

Addtionnal information:

- Language: Python
- Termianl: iTerm2
- OS: OSX

Comment: is there an issue in your program where python code breaks and stops the logging.you check is your code running good

Comment: I'm sure. It's running well. When i didn't use redirect i got the full output on terminal. but when i used `>` i missed some tail of information.

Answer (score 1):

Try running following command

```
./project.py > result.log 2>&1
```

It may be possible that missing lines are going for stderr instead of stdout.

Answer (score 1):

That's the STDOUT flushing problem. It will buffer your output until some internal buffers are full. Try this to set [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) to line buffer mode:

```
stdbuf -oL ./project.py &> result.log
```